# What could cause Android's DisplayMetrics.densityDpi to differ between Release and Debug builds?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, samsung-mobile

I am debugging an issue on the Samsung Galaxy Note 5 Android device running 5.1.1

My issue is related to `DisplayMetrics.densityDpi` which is returning different values under Release and Debug builds (from Eclipse.)

Under `Debug` via Eclipse,  `DisplayMetrics.densityDpi` returns 560 while a release build returns 420.

I am completely stumped by this and I've never seen a device do this. My suspicion in that I have an issue in my `AndroidManifest.xml` ...

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

The code I am using to check is:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    if (metrics.densityDpi == 420) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "420 DPI");
    } else if (metrics.densityDpi == 560) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "560 DPI");
    }
```

The APK, both release and debug, are identical when compared using `aapt dump badging` but the output is curious.

```
        package: name='com.corytrese.games.startraders' versionCode='360' versionName='5.9.35'
      sdkVersion:'4'
      targetSdkVersion:'22'
      application-label:'Star Traders RPG'
      application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png'
      application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
      application-icon-213:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
      application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
      application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png'
      application-icon-480:'res/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png'
      application-icon-640:'res/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png'
      application-icon-65535:'res/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png'
      application: label='Star Traders RPG' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
      application-debuggable
      launchable-activity: name='com.corytrese.games.startraders.menu.MainMenu'  label='Star Traders RPG' icon=''
      uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
      uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch screen unless explicitly made optional'

      main
      other-activities
      supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
      supports-any-density: 'true'
      locales: '--_--' 'ca' 'da' 'fa' 'ja' 'nb' 'de' 'af' 'bg' 'th' 'fi' 'hi' 'vi' 'sk' 'uk' 'el' 'nl' 'pl' 'sl' 'tl' 'am' 'in
      ' 'ko' 'ro' 'ar' 'fr' 'hr' 'sr' 'tr' 'cs' 'es' 'it' 'lt' 'pt' 'hu' 'ru' 'zu' 'lv' 'sv' 'iw' 'sw' 'fr_CA' 'lo_LA' 'en_GB'
       'bn_BD' 'et_EE' 'ka_GE' 'ky_KG' 'km_KH' 'zh_HK' 'si_LK' 'mk_MK' 'ur_PK' 'hy_AM' 'my_MM' 'zh_CN' 'ta_IN' 'te_IN' 'ml_IN'
       'en_IN' 'kn_IN' 'mr_IN' 'mn_MN' 'ne_NP' 'gl_ES' 'eu_ES' 'is_IS' 'es_US' 'pt_PT' 'zh_TW' 'ms_MY' 'kk_KZ' 'uz_UZ'
      densities: '120' '160' '213' '240' '320' '480' '640' '65535' 'gl_ES' 'eu_ES' 'is_IS' 'es_US' 'pt_PT' 'zh_TW' 'ms_MY' 'kk_KZ' 'uz_UZ'
```

densities: '120' '160' '213' '240' '320' '480' '640' '65535'

I do not see 560 or 420 listed, nor do I see my xxxhdpi drawables being referenced.

Comment: Well, now, that's wild. You might run `aapt dump badging` on debug vs. release builds and see what differs in your APK that might have an impact.

Comment: Create a new app and run the same test.

Comment: Also, Samsung-only bugs are common and inscrutable so don't be surprised if it's just that.

Comment: I will `aapt dump badging` and update my question, as well as attempt to reproduce with an APK I can attach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by bugs in Android, whic seem specific to the stock OS image provided with the Note 5. I will report the issue to Google bug tracker.

While the issue is unfortunate, the issue can be worked around by testing with a signed APK with android:debuggable="true". That way you can see the device's 'normal' DPI for applications instead of the buggy one one it assigns to debug builds.

Unfortunately, this issue impacts all types of debug builds that I tested: Android Studio, Eclipse or Ant. None of them are capable of producing a workaround for the issue on the Note 5.